# how to symmetric transposition the coordinates about y = -tan(54º)x line

Tags: math

I'm trying to take coordinates, but I'm not really good at math.
Please tell me how to symmetric transposition (-0.5, -tan(54º)/2) coordinates about y = -tan(54º)x line
Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotate the point and line by 54 degrees clockwise around the origin, in order that the line is aligned with the x-axis:

```
p' = R p
```

where

```
R = [cos(54) -sin(54)]
    [sin(54)  cos(54)]
```

Reflect `p'` about the x-axis:

```
p'' = M p'
```

where

```
M = [1  0]
    [0 -1]
```

then rotate by 54 degrees anti-clockwise about the origin, in order that the line is aligned with the original line:

```
p''' = R^t p
```

where `R^t` is the transpose of the `R` above.

So:

```
p''' = (R^t) M R p

     = [ cos(54) sin(54)] * [1  0] * [ cos(54) sin(54)] p
       [-sin(54) cos(54)]   [0 -1] * [-sin(54) cos(54)]

     = [ cos(54) -sin(54)] * [ cos(54) sin(54)] p
       [-sin(54) -cos(54)]   [-sin(54) cos(54)]

     = [(cos2(54) + sin2(54))  0 ] p
       [ 0                     0 ]

     = [1 0] p
       [0 0]

p''' = [-0.5]
       [ 0  ]
```

Comment: thank you for answer, It's a great helpful